# Histogram to show sampling rate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm having confusion with plotting some data, but here is what I want to do. I have a dataframe with this sample data:

```
>>df.head(20)
 user_id |      trip_id       |       lat        |       lon        | sampling_rate 
---------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+---------------
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9531666666667 | 116.452566666667 |             7
     126 | 125020080511025052 |         39.95305 | 116.452683333333 |            16
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9530666666667 | 116.452916666667 |            44
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9530833333333 | 116.453183333333 |            40
     126 | 125020080511025052 |         39.95335 |        116.45365 |            21
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9532833333333 | 116.453816666667 |            16
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9533166666667 |        116.45405 |            13
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9535666666667 | 116.454383333333 |            24
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9537166666667 |         116.4546 |            16
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9538333333333 | 116.454733333333 |            17
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9540166666667 | 116.454966666667 |            37
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9541833333333 | 116.455133333333 |            18
     126 | 125020080511025052 |         39.95405 | 116.455216666667 |            23
     126 | 125020080511025052 |          39.9539 | 116.455266666667 |            19
     126 | 125020080511025052 | 39.9537333333333 | 116.455333333333 |            42
     126 | 125020080511025052 |         39.95365 | 116.455416666667 |            23
     126 | 125020080512015529 |         40.00705 |        116.32225 |              
     126 | 125020080512015529 |          40.0073 |         116.3225 |            19
     126 | 125020080512015529 |          40.0068 | 116.322083333333 |            66
     126 | 125020080512015529 | 40.0064333333333 | 116.321666666667 |             2
```

This table contains trips GPS traces of users. the `sampling_rate` is shows the GPS sampling for the trips.

I want to show the sampling rate plot, such I can see trips with `1sec` interval, trips with `2-5 seconds` interval, trips with `5-10 seconds` intervals etc...

I would want to have the number of trips on y-axis and interval on x-axis.

Comment: What's the logic behind deciding the interval ranges?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma no more than to show number/percentage of trips within an interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, Use, [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to create bins with the interval of `5sec`:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4))
plt.hist(df['sampling_rate'], bins=np.arange(1, df['sampling_rate'].max() + 5, 5))
plt.xlabel('Sampling Rate')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Distribution of sampling rate')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]